# What is the right thing to do, DialogBox or CreateWindow

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Hello dear experienced users,

I have been programming in windows for some time, and I keep having this question `What is the right thing to do when creating a user interface?`

Is it do to the UI in a resource script and call DialogBox.

Or is it the more tedious way of first create a WNDCLASS structure declare the fields, RegisterClass(&wc) and use CreateWindow, in the end its the same function just the initialization is easier with DialogBox and you loose abit control on the class.

I guess you will ask what the purpose of the application, and ofcourse I could say its for a skinning app (then I would use CreateWindow) and if it were for a simple calculator application I would go for Dialogbox.

BUT what do the pro's go for ?

And please keep in the win32 area as I won't get into a debate whether or not to use QT or Java for those kind of apps, my stand on frameworks is they add alot of unneccessary overhead, java the JRE and QT the extra DLL and .NET all of those add requirements to the user to have those files installed and if not they are required to download all those files. Those files are in the area of > 20 mb. I don't see the justification in that.

Thanks for your answers and the time you took to read my ramblings

Comment: The right thing to do depends on what you're doing. Specific objective questions are a better fit for a Q&A format. Keep ramblings and musings on your blog :P

Comment: Neither way is more "right" than the other.  I prefer dialog boxes for the ease of development.

Comment: I guess you've never encountered the VCL......

Comment: Thanks @Luke. I think its a proper question when we have a lot of programmers who come from different environments.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, using a DialogBox as a main window application seems easy at first but then it gets very uncomfortable, particularly if you do your dialog with `DialogBox()` (instead of `CreateDialog()`:

1. You don't have control over the message loop. Sooner or later you'll want to add a pre-TranslateMessage step, or a idle-processing, or something similar. And for that you'll need to write your own message loop.
2. You do not write the message-procedure but the dialog-procedure. And there are quite a few differences, the most important I can think of:

   a. The return value is not the real `LRESULT` as documented with the message, but a `BOOL` that is mostly useless in all but very few dialog-only messages.

   b. Some important messages are not sent to the dialog procedure, notably WM_CREATE.
3. You do not define thw WNDCLASS of your window, so there are a few things you just cannot change: default HBRUSH, default HICON, wndclass flags, etc. And using `FindWindow` becomes a PITA.
4. You cannot add a menu to a dialog, and a toolbar just looks weird.

Granted, there are workarounds for all of these drawbacks, but that's not the point.

And about the apparent advantages:

1. "You can layout your controls easily using the dialog editor": Actually, the application main window should not have so many user controls. Think of your favorite Windows application, how many controls does it have in the main window? Just leave the controls to the options dialog, or something.
2. "The focus is handled automatically by the underlying dialog": If don't have controls in the main window, this point is moot. And moreover, handling the focus is trivial if you really have to.

I'm not saying that there is no point in making a dialog-based application; just that you should think twice if there is a better way, particularly for non-trivial ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat DialogBox as a complex comprised from several logical parts:

1. Loading dialog definition resource;
2. Creating the dialog window which is accomplished internally via several calls to CreateWindow: the first for the dialog itself and then for its controls found in the template;
3. Blocking owner window to support "modality" and running a message pump: GetMessage -> IsDialogMessage or TranslateMessage+DispatchMessage.

Speaking metaphorically this combination *is useful when the flow of your program must branch depending on user's decision, encapsulating that decision into the single call* to the DialogBox() function. This function really does a lot of work and eases the understanding of your program by hiding asynchronous nature of interaction with raw Win32 windows.

However, this 'high-levelness', specifically the message loop contained within it, may actually raise the complexity of your program, if it already Win32 has message loop and the call to DialogBox is made as a response to a specific message. So in this case you have to take care about nested message loops, especially if you are custom message processing in your main message loop.

In order to avoid such problems, CreateDialog function can be used which is also a complex but only of parts 1 and 2 - it doesn't start message loop. So, you have to provide your own message processing procedure. You should also take care about modality if it is required.

In my practice I used DialogBox only several times for really small utility applications.

Comment: The nested messages are a pain: I found few people among even those "experienced" in WinAPI realized about how functions were silently 'reentred', thus overwriting the previous context data. This can lead to very interesting kind of bugs... My take on it is to avoid adding message loops above the one already existing.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dialog box as the main window for an application is so handy that Visual Studio includes it as a choice when you create a new project. You can lay out the window with the resource editor, and all of the child windows will be created automatically when you create the dialog.

You can even do your own custom background by responding to the dialog's WM_PAINT message.

The dialog box default behavior can also be useful, for example by responding to the TAB key to change control focus.